# jQuery ID+ Class selector

Tags: jquery, html

Currently with my script below it shows the `console.log(inputName)` for the first variable in my code no matter what button is clicked.  How can I alter the script so that I can get the input name foreach row do I have to use an ID + class selector?

**jQuery:**

```
$(function(){


$.fn.editable.defaults.mode = 'inline';

$.fn.editable.defaults.params = function (params) {
    params._token = $("#_token").data("token");
    return params;
};
   var dataURL   = $('.updateField').data('url');
   var inputName = $('.updateField').attr("name");

$('.updateField').editable({
    type: 'text',
    url: dataURL,    
    name: inputName,    
    placement: 'top',
    title: 'Enter public name',
    toggle:'manual',
    send:'always',
    ajaxOptions:{
      dataType: 'json'
    }    
});

$('.edit').click(function(e){ 
      console.log(inputName);  
       e.stopPropagation();
       $('.updateField').editable('toggle');
       $('.edit').hide();
});
    $(document).on('click', '.editable-cancel, .editable-submit', function(){
        $('.edit').show();
    })
```

**HTML Example:**

```
<div class="form-group">
    <label class="col-sm-2 control-label" for="siteName">Website Name</label>

    <div class="col-sm-3">
      <div class="input-group">
        <input class="form-control updateField" data-url="{{ route('generalDataSubmit', 1)}}" data-title="Website Name" name="siteName" placeholder="Email" type="input" value="{{ old('siteName', $siteSettingsData->siteName)}}"> <span class="input-group-btn"><button class="btn btn-default edit" type="button"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon glyphicon-pencil"></span></button></span>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Comment: I have seen your code, it is having only one input field with 'update field' class so it should work but if its not working then you can try by using ID selector.

Comment: @Aparna the rest of my HTML inputs have the class `updateField` however its not working.  How would I do the ID selector as I am guessing I need the ID + Class

Comment: With only ID, it will work. Give it a try.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you have multiple `.updateField` elements, you need to find the target one within your click function by using the `closest()` and then `find()` functions.

```
$('.edit').click(function(e) {
  var container = $(this.closest('.input-group'));
  var input = container.find('.updateField');
  var inputName = input.attr('name');
  var dataURL   = input.data('url');
  console.log(inputName);
  e.stopPropagation();
  input.editable('toggle');
  container.find('.edit').hide();
});
$(document).on('click', '.editable-cancel, .editable-submit', function() {
  $('.edit').show();
});
```

**fiddle:** https://jsfiddle.net/trex005/3oy60m31/

Answer (score 0):

Since you want to select an element that is parent of the element beign clicked you can use `.closest()` to traverse up the DOM and find the first element that matches your selector.Something like this:

```
$('.edit').click(function(e){ 
   var update_field=$(this).closest('.updateField');
    //now you have the element you want so you can do whatever you want with it
     var inputName =update_field.attr('name');
     update_field.editable('toggle');
      ........
      });
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to make your code work for each `.updatefield` separately.

```js
$(function() {

  $.fn.editable.defaults.mode = 'inline';
  $.fn.editable.defaults.params = function(params) {
    params._token = $("#_token").data("token");
    return params;
  };

  $('.updateField').each(function() {

    var currentUpdateField = $(this);
    var dataURL = currentUpdateField.data('url');
    var inputName = currentUpdateField.attr("name");

    currentUpdateField.editable({
      type: 'text',
      url: dataURL,
      name: inputName,
      placement: 'top',
      title: 'Enter public name',
      toggle: 'manual',
      send: 'always',
      ajaxOptions: {
        dataType: 'json'
      }
    });

    currentUpdateField.closest('.input-group').on('click', '.edit', function(e) {
      console.log(inputName);
      e.stopPropagation();
      currentUpdateField.editable('toggle');
      $(this).hide();
    });

  });

  $(document).on('click', '.editable-cancel, .editable-submit', function() {
    $('.edit').show();
  })

});
```

---

The main thing to remember is that jQuery methods that return some value, will return only the requested value of first element in the set (*set being the elements in the jQuery object*).

So when you execute `$('.updateField')` it will return all the elements with this class, but when you do `$('.updateField').data('url')` you will get back the `url` of the first `.updateField` in the DOM.

Comment: What an well in-depth answer and what I am looking for however I am getting an unhanded error event and I do think its to do with the .on('click)

Comment: Do you have a link to this page ? or could you create a live version ?

Comment: Its local sorry,  why do I have to change the on click line anyway?

Comment: I have copy and pasted your code and I now dont get error however I loose the edit function/buttons when the main button is clicked

Comment: As i understand each `.updateField` has its own `.edit` button, right ? So each `.edit` button must know `.updateField` it belongs to (*in the code the `currentUpdateField`*)

Comment: @JessMcKenzie updated answer (*on the `click` handler*). I had misread the html as the `.edit` button being inside the `.updateField` which it's not.